Error with the custom profile directory in selenium "Unknown error: cannot create default profile directory"
I get an error when creating a custom profile using Selenium on Linux:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory

I have write permissions in this directory, I checked.
Here is my code:
profile_path = "/home/David/test"
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=/home/David/test")
driver = webdriver.Remote(options=options)

